# How to crop north and center with morgify in ImageMagick

Tags: images, imagemagick, mogrify

Is there a way to crop an image centered horizontally, but not centered vertically? For example, here is how I would want an image cropped:

[image: expected]

However, using the command `mogrify -crop 250x250 -gravity North cat.jpg`, I get:

[image: gotted]

**Note** I’m going to be doing this in a batch with around 10,000 images of different sizes, so I can’t explicitly pick an exact region to crop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, mathematically you should be dealing with coordinates that are starting at the top left `0,0` (aka: `NorthWest` in ImageMagick terminology) so you would want to position the crop box area to be something like this:

```
(width of image - width of crop area) / 2
```

So you could then conceptually do something like this with your example `mogrify` command:

```
mogrify -crop 250x250+[(width of image - 250)/2]+0 -gravity NorthWest cat.jpg
```

Which is fairly a nice concept, but is not a useful reality. But I just experimented a bit and got this to work for a single test image:

```
CROP_W=250
CROP_H=250
IMG_W=$(identify -format %w test.jpg)
X_OFFSET=$((($IMG_W-$CROP_W)/2))
mogrify -crop ${CROP_W}x${CROP_H}+${X_OFFSET}+0 -gravity NorthWest test.jpg
```

Since ImageMagick’s `-gravity` default is `NorthWest` anyway, you can simplify it by removing the `-gravity` option altogether like this:

```
CROP_W=250
CROP_H=250
IMG_W=$(identify -format %w test.jpg)
X_OFFSET=$((($IMG_W-$CROP_W)/2))
mogrify -crop ${CROP_W}x${CROP_H}+${X_OFFSET}+0 test.jpg
```

And after testing that concept out, I whipped up this Bash script and it works as expected. Just change the `DIRECTORY` value to match the actual directory you plan on acting on. And that `echo mogrify` allows you to see exactly what would be happening if the command were run; remove that `echo` and then let the script go at it if you are happy with the results:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the crop width and height.
CROP_W=250
CROP_H=250

# Set the directory to act on.
DIRECTORY='/path/to/images'

# Use find to find all of the images; in this case JPEG images.
find ${DIRECTORY} -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.JPG" \) |\
  while read FULL_IMAGE_PATH
  do
    # Get the image width with identify.
    IMG_W=$(identify -format %w ${FULL_IMAGE_PATH})

    # Calculate the X offset for the crop.
    X_OFFSET=$((($IMG_W-$CROP_W)/2))

    # Run the actual mogrify command.
    # mogrify -crop ${CROP_W}x${CROP_H}+${X_OFFSET}+0 ${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}
    echo mogrify -crop ${CROP_W}x${CROP_H}+${X_OFFSET}+0 ${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}

  done
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. You'd think that ImageMagick would have a NorthCenter gravity or something.

Answer (score 5):

[Giacomo1968 gave a working solution](https://superuser.com/a/988516/167207), but I think a much easier solution is not to script it, but to use two step conversion. First reduce the height to 250 pixels with *North* gravity, then reduce the width to 250 pixels with *Center* gravity:

```
mogrify -gravity North -crop x250+0+0  cat.jpg
mogrify -gravity Center -crop 250x250+0+0  cat.jpg
```

Alternatively, you could use convert with a non-jpg intermediate image to prevent loss of quality due to the extra conversion to jpg:

```
convert -gravity North -crop x250+0+0 cat.jpg png:- | convert -gravity Center -crop 250x250+0+0 png:- cat.jpg
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer/solution than a complex script.